# PDO Selecting with named parameter (Not possible?)

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Can you use a named parameter in the SELECT portion of a query?

Example:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Available, UserFileName, NameOnServer, :levelid FROM productpage WHERE productID = :prodid');
$stmt->execute(array('levelid'=> $LevelCheck, 'prodid'=> $ProductID));
```

In the code above, "levelid" does not seem to work ($LevelCheck is defined above the included code)

If I replace the named parameter with an actual column name, it works fine.

If this isn't possible, I was wondering if anyone might have a suggestion for me?
There are different columns and the user specifies which column to search.

Thank You for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: No you cannot. Only values can be replaced by bound parameters. best you can do (and probably should do) is make a whitelist and do it with a "normal" variable.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but the same answer applies, so follow the link...